# Want to setup a two-node elastic search cluster on same machine

Tags: elasticsearch

I am on elastic search [7.10.1. For learning purposes want to setup a clutser of two nodes on the same host. Unable to find a configuration which works for me.
I have done same elastic serach installation in two different folders node1 and node2.
node1 elasticsearch.yml file:

```
...
cluster.name: tktest_esclutser
node.name: tkesnode-1
http.port: 19200
transport.port: 19201
discovery.seed_hosts: ["localhost:29200"]
...
```

node2 elasticsearch.yml file:

```
...
cluster.name: tktest_esclutser
node.name: tkesnode-2
http.port: 29200
transport.port: 29201
discovery.seed_hosts: ["localhost:19200"]
...
```

For some reason cluster is not being formed. log file shows master-node could not be discovered.

Comment: Hi - glad you solved this! You should post your own answer about matching transport ports.

Answer (score 0):

Below configuration works perfectly fine for me, **initially you may have to delete the folders inside the data folder of both nodes to start with clean state.**

**Node 1 elasticsearch.yml**

```
cluster.name: es_710
node.name: opster
http.port: 9900
cluster.initial_master_nodes: ["opster"]
```

**Node 2 elasticsearch.yml**

```
http.port: 9910
xpack.ml.enabled: false
cluster.name: es_710
cluster.initial_master_nodes: ["opster"]
```

Comment: Thanks. I found that discovery.seed_hosts: ["localhost:19200"], I have to use transport port 19300 instead of http port. then it worked  for me.